# Load spark graphframe from dtabricks service to neo4j db in the cloud

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, neo4j

im using databricks service via my azure subscription.
I also deployed neo4j db via azure.
im trying to load the  neo4j db from a graphframe object that i built on the databricks platform.

i  have downloaded the spark - neo4j connector, and tried to run the following code:

```
   %scala
   import org.neo4j.spark._ 
   import org.graphframes._ 
   import org.graphframes.GraphFrame

%python
   import pandas as pd
   from pyspark.sql.types import *
   from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
   from graphframes import *

#### create graphframe
   vertex=[ ("a", "Alice", 34),
     ("b", "Bob", 36),
     ("c", "Charlie", 30)]
   labelsV=["id", "name", "age"]

   v=pd.DataFrame.from_records(vertex,columns=labelsV)

## Convert into Spark DataFrame
   vertex = spark.createDataFrame(v)


   Edges=[  ("a", "b", "friend"),
     ("b", "c", ""),
     ("c", "b", "follow")]
   labelsE=["src", "dst", "relationship"]
   e=pd.DataFrame.from_records(Edges,columns=labelsE)
## Convert into Spark DataFrame
   Edges = spark.createDataFrame(e)
```

​

i dont understand how to config to neo4j host from the databricks service.
i tried :

```
%scala
   dbms.connector.http.enabled=true
   dbms.connector.http.listen_address="<url>"
```

i got the following error:

```
command-2039977334603380:47: error: not found: value dbms
val $ires14 = dbms.connector.http.enabled
```

what am i doing wrong?
tnx